# SAP .Net Connector (NCo) / Usage Preconditions

Tags: sap-dotnet-connector

To use SAP .NET Connector (NCo), are there any preconditions? e.g.:

1. License Cost
2. Usage cost in terms frequency/volume of data transfer
3. Other preconditions and/or dependencies

Comment: This is not a programming question. The answer will vary depending on your contract with SAP; talk to your sales rep.

Answer (score 1):

- SAP .NET Connector itself does not require a license
- There is no usage cost for SAP .NET Connector
- No other known pre-conditions / dependencies for SAP Connectors